# Obtener edad a partir de la fecha de nacimiento en Java

Tags: java

Quiero calcular la edad a partir de una fecha de nacimiento en formato `Date`. He probado con este código que parece funcionar bien, pero ¿Es la forma más conveniente?

```
 LocalDate hoy = LocalDate.now();   
 LocalDate nacimiento = usuarioActivo.getFechaNacimiento().toInstant().
           atZone(ZoneId.systemDefault()).toLocalDate(); 
 long edad = ChronoUnit.YEARS.between(nacimiento, hoy);
```

Comment: Revisa http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1116123/how-do-i-calculate-someones-age-in-java, hay buenas respuestas del tema que indicas

Comment: Lo siento, mi inglés es muy limitado

Comment: Para trabajar <code>Dates</code> en Java, se recomienda el uso de la librería [JODA](http://www.joda.org/joda-time). Con ella puedes hacer este código retro-compatible ya que LocalDate viene desde la versión 1.8 de Java.

Comment: @dxcorzo la idea de este sitio es compartir el conocimiento en español antes que en inglés. Lo mejor es proveer una respuesta citando el contenido del sitio en inglés.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

La API de Java 8 para Fechas y Horas es tremenda. La uso y es mi preferida. Puedes usar JODA como te dice @Alejandro Rangel Celis, que es compatible con versiones anteriores de Java.

#### Java 8

La manera en cómo la tienes es válida, pero no del todo correcta porque no tienes en cuenta los meses. Para esto puedes usar la clase [Period](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/iso/period.html):

```
import java.time.LocalDate;
import java.time.Period;
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;

// 01/01/2000
DateTimeFormatter fmt = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd/MM/yyyy");
LocalDate fechaNac = LocalDate.parse("15/08/1993", fmt);
LocalDate ahora = LocalDate.now();

Period periodo = Period.between(fechaNac, ahora);
System.out.printf("Tu edad es: %s años, %s meses y %s días",
                    periodo.getYears(), periodo.getMonths(), periodo.getDays());
```

Salida:

```
Tu edad es: 22 años, 9 meses y 29 días
```

Comment: @Elenasys evita responder a los comentarios de manera agresiva. Si ves un comentario que te ofende, pones una bandera explicando la situación y yo me encargo. Mitsu, evita provocar a las personas publicando comentarios inflamatorios. He borrado los comentarios en ambas publicaciones similares que hayan hecho. Eviten las peleas.

Answer (score 5):

Revisa [Joda](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/), simplifica cálculos de fechas y horas (Joda tambien es la base del nuevo estándar de apis fecha/hora en Java).

Java 8 tiene [algo muy similar](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/) y vale la pena revisarlo.

Ejemplo

```
LocalDate birthdate = new LocalDate (1970, 1, 20);
LocalDate now = new LocalDate();
Years age = Years.yearsBetween(birthdate, now);
```

**[Aquí](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1116123/how-do-i-calculate-someones-age-in-java)** una pregunta similar en el sitio en inglés.

Answer (score 0):

```
public static String getEdad(Date fechaNacimiento) {
    if (fechaNacimiento != null) {
        SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
        StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
        if (fechaNacimiento != null) {
            result.append(sdf.format(fechaNacimiento));
            result.append(" (");
            Calendar c = new GregorianCalendar();
            c.setTime(fechaNacimiento);
            result.append(calcularEdad(c));
            result.append(" años)");
        }
        return result.toString();
    }
    return "";
}

private static int calcularEdad(Calendar fechaNac) {
    Calendar today = Calendar.getInstance();
    int diffYear = today.get(Calendar.YEAR) - fechaNac.get(Calendar.YEAR);
    int diffMonth = today.get(Calendar.MONTH) - fechaNac.get(Calendar.MONTH);
    int diffDay = today.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH) - fechaNac.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
    // Si está en ese año pero todavía no los ha cumplido
    if (diffMonth < 0 || (diffMonth == 0 && diffDay < 0)) {
        diffYear = diffYear - 1;
    }
    return diffYear;
}
```

Comment: podrías explicar la solución? salutes.

Comment: Es puro texto. Sería bueno que expliques qué tiene para aportar esta solución

Answer (score 0):

empiezo a programar java con NetBeans 11 y justo tenia este problema, lo solucione de la siguiente forma: (espero les sirva)

```
import java.time.LocalDate;
import java.time.Month;
import java.time.temporal.ChronoUnit;
     LocalDate fHoy= LocalDate.now();
     LocalDate cumple= LocalDate.of(1990, Month.JUNE, 27);
     long edad= ChronoUnit.YEARS.between(cumple, fHoy); 
     System.out.println("tu edad es: "+edad);
```

Answer (score -1):

```
//declarar una fecha de nacimiento
LocalDate fechaNacimiento.of(1982, Month.June, 22);
//crear fecha de hoy para comparar
LocalDate fechaHoy = LocalDate.now();
//ahora comparar los años de las dos fechas y asi obtener la edad
int edad = fechaHoy.getYear() - fechaNacimiento.getYear();
```

Comment: Hola Artillery, bienvenido/a a stack overflow en español. Te recomiendo que completes el [tour] para conseguir una idea general de cómo funciona el sitio (y tu primera medalla), y leer [answer] donde encontrarás consejos para mejorar tus respuestas. Por ejemplo, puedes formatear el código y texto para que sea más fácil de leer (lo hice por ti), y siempre es bueno añadir alguna descripción y no sólo código (aunque has añadido algún comentario, no estaría de más añadir una descripción de por qué ese enfoque funciona).

Answer (score -1):

```
public void getEdad() {
        
    LocalDate hoy = LocalDate.now() ; 
    
    edad = hoy.getYear()-fechaNAci.getYear();
    
    System.out.println("edad : " + edad);
    
}
```

Comment: Por favor explica lo que hace tu código, las respuestas que solo son un código sin ninguna explicación, están consideradas de baja calidad.