# Añadir años a una fecha

Tags: java

Soy nuevo en Java y tengo la siguiente duda.

Quiero añadir un determinado número de años contenidos en una variable tipo String a otra variable que viene como tipo String que representa una fecha y no sé como hacerlo. Un ejemplo seria:

1. Dadas las siguientes dos variables
   String años = "50"
   String fecha = "20200101"
2. El resultado tiene que ser:

String resultado = "20700101"

Imagino que habría que formatear la fecha y convertirla a fecha para poder sumar pero no tengo claro como hacerlo en Java. Alguna idea?

Gracias

Comment: Saludos, te recomiendo revisar la sección [Cómo preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), luego edita tu pregunta y no olvides agregar lo que has tratado o investigado. ;)

Comment: mira [aca](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/13777/324)... tambien podrias (de una manera no muy fechistica que digamos) multiplicar años * 10000 y sumarselo a fecha....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
String annos = "50"; 
String fecha = "20200101";
int annosFecha = Integer.parseInt(fecha.substring(0, 4));
int periodoAnnos = Integer.parseInt(annos);
int sumaAnnos = annosFecha + periodoAnnos;
String nuevaFecha = Integer.toString(sumaAnnos) + fecha.substring(4);

System.out.println(nuevaFecha);
```

Como en tu formato de fecha los **4** primeros números representan el año de la fecha entonces, usamos la **función substring** para copiar estos **4** primeros números y mediante el **método** **parseInt** de la **clase** **Integer** convertimos de **string** a **integer**. En este caso la **función** **substring** recibe dos parámetros, el primero representa desde que parte de la cadena se va a empezar a copiar, y el segundo la cantidad de caracteres a copiar de la cadena. En nuestro ejemplo sería:

```
fecha.substring(0, 4)
```

Aquí copiamos cuatro caracteres a partir del primer caracter de la cadena original obteniendo por tanto el valor **"2020"**.

Posteriormente convertimos a **integer** el valor del año que queremos aumentar a nuestra fecha.

Hacemos la suma entre la **variable annosFecha** y **periodoAnnos**:

```
2020 + 50 = 2070
```

Y posteriormente armamos un nuevo **string** con la nueva fecha obtenida concatenándola con el dia y el mes que se obtendrán de la cadena original.

En este caso la **función** **substring** tendrá un solo parámetro indicando que se copiará desde la posición indicada hasta la última de la cadena original, ejemplo:

```
fecha.substring(4);
```

Se copia a partir del cuarto caracter de la cadena original hasta el último.

Por último imprimiríamos la nueva fecha.